# How to sort data from list?

Tags: python

I'm working on script rebuilding  from bash to python.
I've list with data from SQL output with lot of servers and computer, which are not update on GLPI DB for a month.

In this list, I need to do some tasks to get proper list :

For start, data type I have :

[OCS ID]

```
 servername01A-2015-05-15-13-42-25
 servernameB02-2018-03-25-05-32-35
 pt-clark-2018-09-25-14-10-05
 PT-Peter-2019-01-01-12-12-05
 G4535-2017-07-14-11-29-25
 G4535-2017-07-14-11-29-25
 g4535-2017-07-14-11-29-25
 pc-rescue-2013-11-11-11-12-05
```

Now, I need to :

- remove duplicates
- remove second part of ID "-2017-07-14-11-29-25" to keep only hostnameA01 or pt-xxxx
- remove some servers (for that, I've a list servers to exclude)
- remove all computer which starting by G**** or g****
- remove all computer which starting by pt- or PT-, PC-, pc-

What I've tried

```
 #exclusion file
    exclusion = open("./exclusion.list", "r")

    #data in
    data_in = open("./list_in", "r")

    #read files
    exclusion_lines = exclusion.readlines()
    data_lines = data_in.readlines()
  #start
    for a in data:
      Z = re.split("(.*)-([0-9]{4}.*)", a[1])
      matchPCPT = re.search("^([Pp][TtCc]-*)", Z[1])
      matchG = re.search("^([Gg][0-9]{4})", Z[1])
      if not matchPCPT and not matchG:
         print Z[1]
```

With this, I ve this output :

```
servername01A
servernameB02
servernameB02
servernameB02
servername01A
```

And some servers that I have to remove (with the exclude list).

Please, I need some help, i'm newbie on python.

Have a good day

EDIT :

Here a full list input

```
mailsrv1a-2015-05-15-13-42-25
mailsrv1b-2015-05-15-13-42-25
mailsrv1c-2015-05-15-13-42-25
mailsrv1a-2015-05-15-13-42-25
datasrvA2-2016-05-15-23-25-25
datasrvB2-2016-05-15-23-25-25
datasrvB2-2016-05-15-23-25-25
g4535-2017-07-14-11-29-25
pc-rescue-2013-11-11-11-12-05
PT-Peter-2019-01-01-12-12-05
pt-clark-2018-09-25-14-10-05
G4535-2017-07-14-11-29-25
benchsrv01rt-2017-07-14-11-29-25
benchsrv02rt-2017-07-14-11-29-25
esxsrv01-2017-07-14-11-29-25
esxsrv02-2017-07-14-11-29-25
solaris10g-2017-07-14-11-29-25
solaris10g-2017-07-14-11-29-25
solaris30g-2017-07-14-11-29-25
test1t-2017-07-14-11-29-25
test2t-2017-07-14-11-29-25
test3t-2017-07-14-11-29-25
test4t-2017-07-14-11-29-25
test5t-2017-07-14-11-29-25
```

Here a list of servers to exclude :

```
benchsrv01rt
benchsrv02rt
solaris30g
solaris10g
test*t
```

Could I use regex in exclusion list ?

Comment: split it in separated jobs. Second part has always 20 chars so you can use slicing `[:-20]` - ie. `"servername01A-2015-05-15-13-42-25"[:-20]`. You can check `text.lower().startswith( ("g", "pt-", "pc-") )`. Using `set(list)` you can remove duplicated elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use standard methods to work with string.

Second part has always 20 chars so you can use slice `[:-20]` to get first part.

Using `text.lower().startswith( ("g", "pt-", "pc-") )` you can skip some names.

Correct names you can add to list (ie. `result`) and you can check if it is on this list to skip duplicated values.

```
text = ''' servername01A-2015-05-15-13-42-25
 servernameB02-2018-03-25-05-32-35
 pt-clark-2018-09-25-14-10-05
 PT-Peter-2019-01-01-12-12-05
 G4535-2017-07-14-11-29-25
 G4535-2017-07-14-11-29-25
 g4535-2017-07-14-11-29-25
 pc-rescue-2013-11-11-11-12-05
 example-2013-11-11-11-12-05'''

data = text.split('\n')

excluded = ['benchsrv01rt', 'benchsrv02rt', 'solaris30g', 'solaris10g']

result = []

for name in data:
    name = name.strip()
    name = name[:-20]
    if not name.lower().startswith(('g', 'pc-', 'pt-')):
        if name not in excluded and name not in result:
           result.append(name)

print(result)
```

The only problem can be digits in `G4535` (if you really need to recognize name with digits) and it may need `regex`

```
    import re

    if not re.match('g[0-9]{4}|pc-|pt-', name, re.IGNORECASE):
        if name not in excluded and name not in result:
           result.append(name)
```

---

**EDIT:** Other problem can be `test*t` which also may need regex.

```
import re

text = '''mailsrv1a-2015-05-15-13-42-25
mailsrv1b-2015-05-15-13-42-25
mailsrv1c-2015-05-15-13-42-25
mailsrv1a-2015-05-15-13-42-25
datasrvA2-2016-05-15-23-25-25
datasrvB2-2016-05-15-23-25-25
datasrvB2-2016-05-15-23-25-25
g4535-2017-07-14-11-29-25
pc-rescue-2013-11-11-11-12-05
PT-Peter-2019-01-01-12-12-05
pt-clark-2018-09-25-14-10-05
G4535-2017-07-14-11-29-25
benchsrv01rt-2017-07-14-11-29-25
benchsrv02rt-2017-07-14-11-29-25
esxsrv01-2017-07-14-11-29-25
esxsrv02-2017-07-14-11-29-25
solaris10g-2017-07-14-11-29-25
solaris10g-2017-07-14-11-29-25
solaris30g-2017-07-14-11-29-25
test1t-2017-07-14-11-29-25
test2t-2017-07-14-11-29-25
test3t-2017-07-14-11-29-25
test4t-2017-07-14-11-29-25
test5t-2017-07-14-11-29-25'''

data = text.split('\n')

excluded = ['benchsrv01rt', 'benchsrv02rt', 'solaris30g', 'solaris10g']

result = []

for name in data:
    name = name.strip()
    name = name[:-20]
    if not re.match('g[0-9]{4}|pc-|pt-|test[0-9]t', name, re.IGNORECASE):
        if name not in excluded and name not in result:
           result.append(name)

print(result)
```

---

**EDIT:** you can also use list `excluded` and `excluded = '|'.join(excluded)` to create regex which you can use in `re.match()`

```
excluded = [
    'benchsrv01rt',
    'benchsrv02rt',
    'solaris30g',
    'solaris10g',
    'g[0-9]{4}',
    'pc-',
    'pt-',
    'test[0-9]t',
]

excluded = '|'.join(excluded)
#print(excluded)

result = []

for name in data:
    name = name.strip()
    name = name[:-20]
    if not re.match(excluded, name, re.IGNORECASE):
        if not in result:
           result.append(name)

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm gonna improve the script

Answer (score 0):

here is an example (it contains some Python list comprehension)

```
# init list
datalist = [ 'servername01A-2015-05-15-13-42-25',
             'servernameB02-2018-03-25-05-32-35',
             'pt-clark-2018-09-25-14-10-05',
             'PT-Peter-2019-01-01-12-12-05',
             'G4535-2017-07-14-11-29-25',
             'G4535-2017-07-14-11-29-25',
             'g4535-2017-07-14-11-29-25',
             'pc-rescue-2013-11-11-11-12-05' ]

# 1. remove duplicates
datalist = list(set(datalist))

# 2. remove second part of ID
for i,data in enumerate(datalist):
    tmp = '-'.join([tmp_str for tmp_str in data.split('-') if not tmp_str.isdigit()]) 
    datalist[i] = tmp

# 3. remove some servers
# I skipped this step since you did not provide the list of servers to exclude

# 4. remove all computer which starting by G**** or g****
datalist = [d for d in datalist if not d.startswith("G") and not d.startswith("g") ]


# 5. remove all computer which starting by pt- or PT-, PC-, pc-
for prefix in ['pt-', 'PT-', 'PC-', 'pc-']:
    datalist = [d for d in datalist if not d.startswith(prefix) ]

# 6. sort
datalist = sorted(datalist)
```

The final output is:

[image]

Comment: in `startswith()` you can use tuple with all versions `startswith( ('g', 'G', 'pt-', 'PT-', 'PC-', 'pc-') )` to make code shorter.

Comment: @furas You are correct, it's a trick I did not know before, thank you!

Comment: interesting, thanks a lot, it will be a good base to improve my skills in python because in the futur i will write another script like this.
I have edited my main post to bring some data for step 3